# linking a NSTimer to a NSProgressIndicator

Tags: cocoa, nstimer, nsprogressindicator

I need to make an `NSTimer` that will tell another class to fire in 10 seconds, and I would also like to use it to animate a determinate `NSProgressIndicator`. I also need to know how to change my indeterminate progress indicator to determinate. I was able to find a Apple doc on this, however a more in-depth explanation would help.

Answer (score 4):

From indeterminate to determinate `NSProgressIndicator` You can change in IB. Select Your progressIndicator and go to Attributes inspector and uncheck *Indeterminate* checkbox like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Or it can be done programatically:

```
[progressIndicatorOutlet setIndeterminate:NO];
```

**Note:** progressIndicatorOutlet is Your `NSProgressIndicator` outlet, so don't forget to `IBOutlet` it.

---

**Determinate NSProgressIndicator** animation:

It's very simple just set and change value like this:

```
[progressIndicatorOutlet setDoubleValue:10];
```

**Note:** progressIndicatorOutlet is Your `NSProgressIndicator` outlet, so don't forget to `IBOutlet` it.

---

**NSTimer:**

Simple timer example:

```
//Place this where You want to call class after 10 sec. (for example: when button pressed)
//It will call class with name callAfter10sec after 10 sec. Place in there what You need to do. 

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(callAfter10sec:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Don't forget to add class which I mentioned in comments like this:

```
-(void)callAfter10sec:(NSTimer *)time {
    // Do what You want here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

Using the following way we can achieve what is expected

```
NSInteger progressValue;
NSTimer *timerObject;

progressValue = progressMaxValue;

timerObject = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(incrementProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[timerObject fire];
[self.progressBar setMinValue:progressMinValue]; 
[self.progressBar setMaxValue:progressMaxValue];
[self.progressBar setDoubleValue:progressValue];

- (void)incrementProgressBar {
    // Increment the progress bar value by 1
    [self.progressBar incrementBy:1.0];
    progressValue--;
    [self.progressBar setDoubleValue:progressValue];
}
```